# Does relation (employee, address, phone) violate 3rd Normal Form?

Tags: database, normalization

Suppose we have relation like `(employee, address, phone)` - or, something like this - `(userid, login_name, password)` for example - with first field being the key.

It feels like it is not "normalized" since we can split it in two (employee, address) and (employee, phone) - especially good if some employee do not have a phone (or have two).

As I understand it does not violate 2NF and complies with 1NF requirements (at least until we try insert null for phone) - but I could not show how it violates 3NF.

So the question is - whether such relation complies with 3rd normal form or not. Or does it violate some other I did not think about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I understand that the problem is in messing two different kind of relations in this question:

- if we decide that one employee could have only one phone, than `employee` is a candidate key and the relation satisfies requirements of 2nd and 3rd normal forms;
- but if the employee could have several phones, then `employee` is no more a key - instead the tuple `(employee, phone)` becomes a candidate key - and if so, 2nd normal form is violated because `address` depends only on the part of the candidate key - `employee` field.

I'm sorry for involuntarily bewildering whoever reads the question.